# Google plus profile pic url is not getting

Tags: android, google-signin

In my android app there is google plus login button.Google plus login works fine in my app. I use  this code to access url of google plus profile pic

```
String profileurl=Account.getPhotoUrl().toString();
```

When I use this code.I got  errors  caused by this reason

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference
```

**What should I do to get profile picture url of google plus account?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message clearly states, you are invoking the method "toString()" on a null object, you can either change your code to catch null instances

```
if (Account.getPhotoUrl() != null){
    String profileurl=Account.getPhotoUrl().toString();
}
```

or make sure that "getPhotoURL()" never returns null

Answer (score 1):

It seems your **Account** is null and you are trying to access value on null object thats why you are getting `null` `pointer` `exception`. So please try to get like this

```
GoogleSignInResult result;// its your google result
GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();// here your Account value is null

String profileURL = "";
if (acct != null)
   profileURL = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
```

Comment: @User1278 Thank you and please subscribe my youtube channel for more updates on mobile(Android & ios). **https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCA5HRmlkT7bqbO56EIlT0UQ**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with firebase.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin